# DropDownList Displays Blank Value if Selected Value Not in Source

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, telerik

I would like to allow a dropdownlist to show values that were previously selected but are now removed from the dropdownlist source.  Instead of displaying blank.  The dropdownlist is in a grid column.

**Grid:**

```
...
columns.ForeignKey(p => p.CurrentCategory, @Model.LookupCategory, "CategoryName", "CategoryName").Width(160);
...
```

**Template editor**

```
@using System.Collections

@(
 Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)       
        .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData[ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("") + "_Data"])
        .ValuePrimitive(true)        
        .AutoWidth(true)
)
```

So to explain in more detail:  The CurrentCategory column is a text column (not an id column) and the user can select from a list of items found in the LookupCategory.  However if an item is removed from the LookupCategory the value should still be displayed in instances where the user had already selected that value for the CurrentCategory.

Currently if a row contains a CurrentCategory value that is not in the LookupCategory list it is displayed as blank.

Perhaps I have to use a combobox instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might add to your view model another property AllCategory containing the union of LookupCategory and the deleted items.
This property will be used by the grid to bind the menu choice and the LookupCategory property will be used as the dropdown source.

See below how to distinguish between the two while using the foreign key column template.

```
columns.ForeignKey(p => p.CurrentCategory, Model.AllCategory, "CategoryName", "CategoryName")
       .EditorViewData(new {lookupCategory = Model.LookupCategory})
.Width(160);


@using System.Collections

@(
 Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)       
        .BindTo((SelectList) ViewData["lookupCategory"])        
        .ValuePrimitive(true)        
        .AutoWidth(true)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.  Is there no way to avoid using ViewData and populate directly from the model?

Comment: I don't think so